# Rectangle's corners being automatically rounded upon creation or copy

Tags: inkscape, shapes

Whenever I create a rectangle, the corners are rounded. I can use the circular handle on the top-right corner of the shape to remove the rounded corner, but if I then copy this rectangle, the resulting rectangle has again rounded corners.

I would like to know how to disable this automatic rounding, or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the rectangle, and make sure you have the Rectangle Tool selected in the Toolbar.

In the Tool Controls along the top, hit the ***Make Corners Sharp*** button

[image]